# Oauth 2.0: I can't get profile info from Google "token info endpoint" by using id_token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm trying to get user info (profile,email) from Google by using OAuth 2.0.

But "token info endpoint" did not return profile info even though I set "profile" to scopes.

I followed the doc of Google sign-in for iOS. (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth)

I couldn't figure out why this end point doesn't return profile info as I expected.

First I get Token by oauth2.0 (as a test, I got token using Rails)

`def gmail
    require 'oauth2'
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(
      'Client-id',
      'client-secret',
      {
        site: 'https://accounts.google.com/',
        authorize_url: 'o/oauth2/auth',
      }
    )
    redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url(
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/google_signup',
      scope: 'email profile',
    )
  end`

`token = client.auth_code.get_token(
      params[:code],
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/gmail_signup',`

and I get `id_token`from this token.

then, send GET request to "token info endpoint".

`"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=id_token"`

but response didn't contain profile info.

```
{
  "azp": "azp",
  "aud": "aud",
  "sub": "sub",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "at_hash": "at_hash",
  "exp": "TIMESTAMP",
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "iat": "iat",
  "alg": "alg",
  "kid": "kid"
}
```

The response was supposed to be like this.

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",
 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```